# Get records from most recent month

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table that stores title and publication (DATE format), and need to get all records from the most recent month/year.

```
select title, pub_date FROM news ORDER BY pub_date DESC
```

Comment: So what's wrong with `ORDER BY pub_date DESC`?

Comment: @Ende Neu I need only records from most recent month.

Comment: @Miki most recente month = the latest month that has records

Comment: @marcelo2605 now we get it... we will try. ready Miki :)?

Comment: @albciff Thanks for the effort guys

Comment: Guys, a guy from portuguese forum solved the problem: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30891/pegar-os-registros-do-m%C3%AAs-mais-recente?noredirect=1#30894

Comment: Well, I solved it the the same way, too ;)

Comment: Yes!!, @Miki put the right answer, only miss the `year()` but he knows the concept!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT title, pub_date 
FROM news 
WHERE MONTH(pub_date) = (SELECT MONTH(MAX(pub_date)) FROM news ORDER BY pub_date DESC LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY pub_date DESC
```

Comment: `month()` only take the month in account not the current year (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month), OP is requiring current month and year.

Comment: It worked. But if I do not have any record in the current month, it can not get records from the most recent month.

Comment: you need most recent month with any record?